# Call async func without waiting for result (execute in background)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, web3js, ethers.js

My **Vue.js** code:

```js
function dreamOn() {
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txFin);
    return;
}
```

I want to send this transaction, but I don't want to wait for the result of sendSignedTransaction (a transaction sends for 5 seconds, it's too long). I want just do return, and the function should execute in the background. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes — remove the await! await is syntaxic sugar made to wait for a result before proceeding. You dont need to use it.